# IndexError: list index out of range после обработки xml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, парсер

Из файла xml:

```
<items>
<item id="26479957">
    <genre>статья в журнале</genre>
    <type>научная статья</type>
    <source>
        <journal>
            <title>Современные научные исследования и инновации</title>
            <eissn>2223-4888</eissn>
            <publisher>Общество с ограниченной ответственностью Международный научно-инновационный центр</publisher>
            <country>RUS</country>
            <town>Москва</town>
            <vak>no</vak>
            <rsci>no</rsci>
            <wos>no</wos>
            <scopus>no</scopus>
        </journal>
</item>
<item id="21373499">
    <genre>статья в журнале</genre>
    <type>научная статья</type>
    <source>
        <journal>
            <title>Исторические, философские, политические и юридические науки, культурология и искусствоведение. Вопросы теории и практики</title>
            <issn>1997-292X</issn>
            <publisher>Общество с ограниченной ответственностью Издательство Грамота</publisher>
            <country>RUS</country>
            <town>Тамбов</town>
            <vak>no</vak>
            <rsci>no</rsci>
            <wos>no</wos>
            <scopus>no</scopus>
        </journal>
</item>
</items>
```

Пытаюсь вытащить eissn, если его в текущем теге нет, то вытаскиваю issn:

```
def get_issn_eissn(item) -> str:
    for issn in item:
        if issn in item:
            publ_issn = item.find_all("issn")[0]
            return publ_issn.text
        else:
            publ_eissn_issn = item.find_all("eissn")[0]
            return publ_eissn_issn.text
```

Выходит ошибка: list index out of range. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу исправить данную ошибку? Заранее благодарна за ответ

Comment: Нашла вот такой не очень удобный вариант:

def get_issn(item) -> str:
    for issn in item:
        if issn in item:
            publ_issn = item.find("issn")
            return publ_issn
        else:
             break

Comment: У вас сломанный XML - tag `<source>` не закрыт. Ваша задача найти `eissn`/`issn` в одном элементе или найти их все во всем документе?

Comment: Все просто: если `item.find_all(...)` возвращает пустой список, то `item.find_all(...)[0]` вызывает ту ошибку, проверяйте что список не пустой, перед тем как вызывать `[0]`, или используйте поиск, который возращает 1 элемент -- `find`

Comment: Во всем документе. tag <source> не закрыт, т.к. я в ручную невнимательно обрезала файл

Comment: сделала через find. Все сработало. Спасибо!